# Why does the realloc invalidates my data for custom allocator?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have preallocated a big chunk of memory using **malloc** for my stack allocator, however I want it to be able to expand its memory. The alloc function looks like this:

```
void* _stack = malloc(4096);
```

...

```
template <class T>
T* allocate(const std::size_t& blockSize)
{
    std::size_t newMemoryBlock = (std::size_t)_stack + _stackHead;

    _stackHead += blockSize;

    return (T*)newMemoryBlock;
}
```

This approach works fine(also with alignment[even though its not in the example]). However, problems appear when the stack tries to realloc its buffer via this function:

```
static void allocateMoreMemory(void*& srcPtr, std::size_t& srcBufferSize, uint sizeMultiplier = 2)
{
    //Double the size
    srcBufferSize *= sizeMultiplier;

    void* newBuffer = realloc(srcPtr, srcBufferSize);

    if (!newBuffer)
    {
        std::cout << "Reallocation failed" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        srcPtr = newBuffer;
}
```

And in the problem, the usage is like this :

```
StackAllocator<6> allocator;

std::vector<int*> vector(2);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    vector[i] = allocator.allocate<int>();
    *vector[i] = i;
}

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    std::cout << *vector[i] << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, it allocates a space for first integer and then when it tries to allocate the second one, it needs to reallocate(because we initialized the allocator just for 6 bytes). After change the first integer value changes to random value. Console output from the std::out

[image: Console output showing the content of my vector]

Is it possible to use realloc for this case of use? Or is it happening because I´m casting the memory used to different types? If its possible, how to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is

```
vector[i] = (int*)allocator.allocate<int>();
```

at some point, `realloc` will probably change the memory block to get one which fits the bigger memory.

All previous occurrences of `vector[i]` then become invalid, you'll have to update all previous values (not very handy in your context)

Your allocator must return distinct memory areas and cannot use `realloc`.

If you need contiguous memory for all your vectors, you have to create a higher level object that handles reallocation & update of all existing `vector` elements, or an object which holds the start of the buffer and provides methods to return addresses of vector slices (without storing them anywhere else) so updates aren't needed.

If you don't need contiguous memory, just stick to vector of vectors (`std::vector<std::vector<int> >`) and drop the `malloc`/`realloc` C calls.

Comment: I editted the question (as the explicit typing is not needed because its already made in the allocate function), does it influence your answer? Also, I think i dont understand, do you mean that the problem is because I used vector for the test?

Comment: answers: no, and no :) using `vector` isn't an issue. Even in pure C you'd have this issue. see my edit.

Comment: Actually the vector stuff was just a testing, I wanted to use it also for other variables(that need dynamic allocation). As you suggested using vectors, one approach I´ve tried was to keep vector of void*(allocated chunks of memory that will be bigger and bigger) and when it needs more memory it just pushes back the vector with doubled memory chunk and use it for allocations. However I was wondering if there is a way to have a contiguous memory(realloc). In the allocator I keep only void*, offset variable and vector of block sizes so i know how much bytes to cut off at pop_back() function.

Comment: reallocating to reduce the size won't change the pointer (well, not likely :)) you _can_ have a contiguous memory, but you have to handle all the data at the same location (in the same object). As soon as you dispatch addresses in independent variables, you expose yourself to pointer invalidity when realloc decides to move the block. Keep all wrapped in one big object.

Comment: I think I will try the approach with saving the chunks of memory in vectors. The "manager" object that updates the objects would be more overhead I think because it would need to know the exact types allocated from the exact memory pieces. Thanks for help!

Comment: Just wondering, how would you design the kind of "manager object" so it updates the values? Do you mean it could have just a vector of void* and then use the reinterpret_cast to update the value of the corresponding piece of memory block in the new allocated place?

Comment: I would use only 1 pointer, and a method to return the ith vector. No need for vectors, don't store the pointers, just recompute them (if sizes are fixed, a multiplication does the job). If you have complex/variable sizes, then recompute addresses everytime realloc returns something different, don't store addresses from outside the object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159816/discussion-between-pins-and-jean-francois-fabre).